# SQL server select query with parenthesis

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a table in sql server
called user,
but when i tried to query the table
it only works like this approch (with parenthesis):

```
Select * from [user]
```

when i try:

```
select * from user
```

it dosent seems to work 'incorrect synax near the keyword 'user'

why i need to add those parenthesis i know i need to add Parenthesis if there is a space between like colum name "first name"

why it is not working?

Comment: user is reserve word for sql server that's why you are getting this error , you need to use [user]

Comment: It is reserved keyword for `SQL Server`, you should not use it. You can check it `select user` will display current user name.

Comment: Those are not parentheses.  Parentheses are curved (`(` and `)`).  Those are square braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write `SELECT` statement without square brackets for database tables, columns. When you use square brackets, then you explicitly says to SQL Server engine to select data from table `user`:

```
Select * from [user]
```

But when you write `select * from user`, then SQL engine thinks not about table `user`, but about [reserved keyword user](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). The correct query to see database user name looks like this:

```
select user
```